# A proposition about local complete ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(A,\mathfrak{M}, K)$ be a **complete local ring with algebraically closed residue field** $K=A/\mathfrak{M}$ and $f ∈ A[x]$ a polynomial of degree $n$ whose derivative $f'$
satisfies $(f, f′) = (1)$ in the ring $A[x]$. Show that $A[x]/(f)$ is isomorphic to a finite direct product of $n$ copies of $A$.

---

Proof (attempt)

- Let $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$. Let $\overline{f}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \overline{a_k}x^k$ the polynomial obtained from $f(x)$ considering the image of the coefficients $a_0,a_1,\dots, a_n\in A$ in $A/\mathfrak{M}$. Since $(f,f')=A[x]$, we have that $(\overline{f},\overline{f'})=K[x]$.
- Using the derivative criterion we deduce that $\overline{f}$ has no multiple roots, then - since $K$ is algebraically closed - $\overline{f}(x)=\overline{a_n}(x-\beta_1)(x-\beta_2)\cdot\dots\cdot (x-\beta_n)$ for some $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n\in K$, with $\beta_i\ne\beta_j$ for all $i\ne j$.
- I observe that $\overline{f'}(\beta_i)\ne\overline{0}$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ because the greatest common divisor of $\overline{f}$ and $\overline{f'}$ is $\overline{1}$ (remember that $(\overline{f},\overline{f'})=K[x]$).
- By the hypothesis $A$ is a local complete ring, then I can apply Hensel Lemma through which I can deduce that $\forall i=1,\dots, n\,\,\quad\exists ! \,b_i\in\beta_i: f(b_i)=0$. Clearly, $b_i\ne b_j$ for all $i\ne j$ because otherwise we would have $\beta_i=\beta_j$ for some $i\ne j$, contradiction. This means that $b_1,\dots, b_n$ are $n$-distinct roots of the polynomial $f$. This polynomial has degree equal to $n$, then $f(x)=a_n\prod_{k=0}^n(x-b_i)$.
- Now, we observe that by the Chinese Reminder Theorem (we can use it because the ideals $(x-b_1),\dots, (x-b_n)$ are pairwise coprime) $A[x]/(f)\cong\prod_{k=1}^n A[x]/(x-b_i)\cong A^n$.

This is my proof. Can you tell me if it is right or not, please?

Comment: You don't assume that $f$ is monic? With $f=2x^3+x\in \Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ then $\gcd(f,f')=1$ and clearly $f$ doesn't split as you said.

Comment: Hi, would you consider [converting your attempt to a solution as per this meta suggestion?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29126/29335https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29126/29335).  If you spent a lot of time writing a high quality answer and are not suspicious of any problems with it, there is no good reason not to post it as a self-answer (and a lot of good reasons *for* posting it as a self-answer.)

Comment: @rschwieb $\Bbb{Z}_2$ the $2$-adic integers, or $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\Bbb{Z}_2[\zeta_{2^n-1}]$ if you want it to have an algebraically closed residue field.

Comment: @reuns Of course,  my bad :)

Comment: More obvious with $A=\Bbb{C}[[t]], f = tx+1, \gcd(f,f')=\gcd(tx+1,t)=\gcd(tx+1-tx,t)=\gcd(1,t)=1$ and $A[x]/(f)\cong\Bbb{C}((t))$ is not isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: Ok, thanks to everyone. Have you got any idea about how can the text of the exercise be modified in order to be true?

Comment: I said so, assume that $f$ is monic. $\gcd(f,f')=1$ then gives that $f$ is separable $\bmod \mathfrak{M}$, by Hensel lemma it has $\deg f$ distinct roots in $A$, so it splits completely in $A$, the differences of the roots are non-zero in the residue field so the $(x-b_i)$ are pairwise coprime from which $A[x]/(f)=A[x]/\prod_i (x-b_i)\cong \prod_i A[x]/(x-b_i)$.

Comment: @reuns Ok, thank you! Just a last question: the reason why the ideals $(x-b_1),\dots, (x-b_n)$ are coprime, is that each ideal $(x-b_i)$ is a maximal ideal, right?

Comment: $\frac1{b_j-b_i} (x-b_i)-\frac1{b_j-b_i} (x-b_j) = 1$

Comment: @reuns Ok thanks! Here you are using the fact that, since $b_j-b_i\notin\mathfrak{M}$, we have ($A$ is local, then $A\setminus\mathfrak{M}\subseteq A^*$) $b_j-b_i\in A\setminus\mathfrak{M}$, right?